# Trouble with intersection between line segments

Tags: java, android, math

I have a path stored as points in an arraylist and I want to check if the line segments are intersecting. For some unknown reason it's not working! I don't get any message in the LogCat despite that I'm drawing a shape that intersects. Preciate if someone could see what I have done wrong or have suggestions how to improve code.

```
    // Intersection control
    if(touchActionUp) {

        // Loop throw all points except the last 3
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size()-3; i++) {
            Line line1 = new Line(points.get(i), points.get(i+1));

            // Begin after the line above and check all points after that
            for (int j = i + 2; j < points.size()-1; j++) {
                Line line2 = new Line(points.get(j), points.get(j+1));

                // Call method to check intersection
                if(checkIntersection(line1, line2)) {
                    Log.i("Intersection", "Yes!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the method:

```
    // Method to check for intersection between lines
private boolean interceptionControl(Line line1, Line line2) {
    int x1 = line1.pointX1;
    int x2 = line1.pointX2;
    int x3 = line2.pointX1;
    int x4 = line2.pointX2;

    int y1 = line1.pointY1;
    int y2 = line1.pointY2;
    int y3 = line2.pointY1;
    int y4 = line2.pointY2;

    // Check if lines are parallel

    int denom = (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1);

    if(denom == 0) { // Lines are parallel
        // ??
    }

    double a = ((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / denom;
    double b = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3)) / denom;

    // Check for intersection
    if( a >= 0.0f && a <= 1.0f && b >= 0.0f && b <= 1.0f) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" in which way? error? not detecting intersections right?

Comment: It's not detecting a intersection

Comment: Does test === denom ? I don't see "test" declaration

Comment: Sorry that was old code! It should be denom!

Comment: Also you have interceptionControl and checkIntersection - two different functions?

Comment: Try to put numbers in x1, x2, ... declarations instead of reading them from your Line class. If that will work, error is in class usage rather than algorithm. And try it just on two lines - you need to test on simple cases before complicating things. Remove the loop.

Comment: But the Line class just hold values and nothing more. But I will try

Comment: I removed the loop and used other values to x1, x2.... but still not working! :( Is there a better and perhaps simplier way to check for intersections?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of points/lines where the algorithm fails?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `int` for coordinates and so it does integer division (i.e., 3/2 = 1). This might be the reason when you are dividing by `denom`. You can fix it by dividing by `((double)denom)` instead of simply `denom`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working! I have tested ((double)denom). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Mate, the code works perfectly fine for me. Which points do you put in  for test?